# Is there any other way to print mysql table in html like a matrix form?

Tags: php, css, mysql, html, xampp

i am currently working on a college project.The requirement is to print the data(subject ,class,section) to the corresponding day and hour in html table.I tried my best to achieve the requirement but the html table just prints again and prints the next value where i want all my data to be printed in a single table to corresponding day and hour .

here is the image of my database :
[image]

And here is my output which am not satisfied with:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/oa8OLyT]

Here is my query:

```
<?php  
include "conn.php";
include ("/styles/faculty_menu.php");
session_start();
$uid=$_SESSION['userid'];
$cuid=strtoupper("$uid");
$qrun=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE id='$cuid'");
$udata=mysql_fetch_assoc($qrun);
$q2run=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE id='$cuid'");
$u2data=mysql_fetch_assoc($q2run);
$urole=$udata['role'];
$comp=strtoupper("$u2data[subject]");
$day = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednessday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
?>
```

i expect the output to be a single table with all the respected data in the corresponding place.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <center>Day/Hour</center>
        </th>
        <?php 
            for ($i=1; $i <=8 ; $i++) { 
            ?>
        <th>
            <center><?php echo $i; ?></center>
        </th>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
        while ($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($q2run)) {
           for ($d=0; $d <6 ; $d++) { 
           ?>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <center><?php echo $day[$d]; ?></center>
        </th>
        <?php 
            for ($r=1; $r <=8; $r++) {

                ?>
        <td>
            <?php 
                if ($rows['day']==$day[$d] && $rows['hour']==$r) {
                    echo $rows['class'],$rows['section'],$rows['subject'];

                }
                ?>
        </td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } 
        }
              ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Please upload your code as well . It's difficult to answer your question

Comment: hai @MD.JubairMizan sorry for inconvenience,this is my second question at stackoverflow and and really don't know how this thing works and i have approved your modifications.can you please help me with my code

Comment: This is a programming site, not a photography site. Please, post your code, not a photograph of your code. We want to read, copy&paste, and debug your code, not critique its use of color and perspective. Although, if I *may* critique your use of color, on my screen, your photograph is completely unreadable, which is precisely *why* you should post your code as code, not as a photograph.

Comment: @rohitsingh https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan thank you . i have edited my code  can you help me now please?

Comment: @rohitsingh Where is your query

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan i have edited my query too !

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan is it okay now ??

Comment: @rohitsingh checkout my answer and let me know

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan okay  will try

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan code isn't working it shows empty table

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan Brother i have another issue can u help me out

Comment: @rohitsingh Put the another question on stack

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan i have placed my question on stack and mentioned you in the comment section . here is the link to my question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54699148/i-am-unable-to-find-if-the-row-already-exists-in-mysql-db-using-time-function-in?noredirect=1#comment96185854_54699148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changes some logic of your code . Hope this will work

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <center>Day/Hour</center>
            </th>
            <?php 
            for ($i=1; $i <=8 ; $i++)
                echo '<th><center>'.$i.'</center></th>';
            ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
        for($d=0;$d<6;$d++){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <center><?php echo $day[$d]; ?></center>
                </th>

                <?php
                for ($r=1; $r <=8; $r++) {
                    echo '<td>';
                        while ($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($q2run)) {
                            if($rows['day']==$day[$d] && $rows['hour']==$r)
                                echo $rows['class'],$rows['section'],$rows['subject'];
                        }
                    echo '</td>';
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        <?php
        } 
        ?>

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: after replacing my code with your code it shows empty rows and columns in my table

Comment: @rohitsingh can you snap a screenshot

Comment: Can you just remove the condition of `if($rows['day']==$day[$d] && $rows['hour']==$r)` THis is for just checking while loop are working . Let me know what you getting by screenshot

Comment: As you mentioned to remove the if condition ijust commented the condition it shows me all the values in a single cell . here is the snap : https://imgur.com/a/rqeh8M0

Comment: Take me a screenshot of this

Comment: can you connect through teamviewer?

Comment: Come with anydesk

Comment: yes brother i tried but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."