# I am unable to find if the row already exists in mysql db using time function in php mysql query?

Tags: mysql, html, xampp, php-5.6

i am currently working on a module where faculty can post attendance to the students by selecting a dropdown(select box) which is generated dynamically by the information given by the faculty.When faculty selects a particular year and section respected student list is retrived and displayed   in a table.But the requirement is once the attendance is posted to a particular class/section on a particular it cannot be opened again by the faculty

I have tried using mysql_num_rows() function to check if any rows are already present in the db or not on that particular date.But its not working the way i wanted

here is my entire code of the module excluding db file

```
<form action="take.php" method="Post">
<br>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
    <tr>
        <th>S.no</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Roll Number</th>
        <th>Present</th>
        <th>Absent</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['search'])) 
            { 
            $stu="Student";
            $yr=$_POST['year']; 
            $se=$_POST['section'];                             

            $subdr=mysql_query("SELECT subject FROM schedule WHERE id='$cuid' AND day='$d' AND class='$yr' AND section='$se'");
            $subj=mysql_fetch_assoc($subdr);
                $dis_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $subj_d=$subj['subject'];
                $display=mysql_query("select * from attendance_records where id='$cuid' AND ondate='".$dis_date."' And subject='$subj_d'");
                $rec=mysql_num_rows($display);
                if($rec){
                echo "Records posted";
            }
            else{
                $display=mysql_query("select name,id from login where role='$stu' AND academic='$yr' AND section='$se'");

                $sno=0;
                $count=0;

                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($display)) {
        $sno++;
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $sno  ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['name']  ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $row['name']  ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['id']  ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']  ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="attendance_status[<?php echo $count ?>]" value="Present" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="attendance_status[<?php echo $count ?>]" value="Absent" required>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $count++;
        }
        }
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=5>
            <center><label><?php echo "Subject : ".$subj['subject']; ?></label></center>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="yr" value="<?php echo $_POST['year']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="set" value="<?php echo $_POST['section']; ?>">
    <?php 
        } ?>
</table>
<center><input   type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" >
</center>
</div>
```

the expected output should display a message saying "Records posted" based on query like :

```
$dis_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$subj_d=$subj['subject'];
$display=mysql_query("select * from attendance_records where id='$cuid' 
   AND ondate='".$dis_date."' And subject='$subj_d'");
$rec=mysql_num_rows($display);
if($rec){
 echo "Records posted";
 }
 else{
  #display the student list
 }
```

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan can you please help me out brother?

Comment: Why are you using such archaic and insecure code?

Comment: @Strawberry actually i'm a beginner ,i have comleted my course and started to explore and learn thing .How can make my code more secure ? I just want to know thanks in advance

Comment: The `mysql_XXX` functions are obsolete. They've been deprecated for years, and have been removed entirely from the latest PHP versions. You should use `mysqli_XXX` or `PDO`, and use prepared statements instead of concatating variables into the SQL.

Comment: Now i got to know the use of mysqli_XXX functions ,i really thought that both are same and are ment to work the same with different syntax and our sir didn't taught us about all these things anyways thanks for letting me know @Barmar

Comment: Unfortunately, many schools do not update their curriculum.

Comment: @Barmar sad reality but true

Comment: Topicstarter @Barmar is right i would use the OOP mysqli interface over the procedural interface which Barmar suggested using..the OOP interface less verbose.. `$mysqli = new mysqli(...); $mysqli->prepare($query); `   then using `$mysqli = mysqli_connect(...); mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query)`.. See the difference what i mean with verbose but it is still a matter of tast which interface you are going to use.

Comment: @rohitsingh update your attendance_records table schema

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan sorry i was out of town just returned back home today.Can you please check it out through anydesk bro please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is:

```
$dis_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

so `$dis_date` contains both a date and a time of day. The query will only match if the records in the table have the exact same time of day, not just the same date.

You should leave the time out of the variable:

```
$dis_date=date("Y-m-d");
```

If the datatype of the column in the table is `DATETIME`, you also need to filter out the time from that, with:

```
AND DATE(ondate)='$dis_date' And subject='$subj_d'"
```

You don't need to do this if the datatype is `DATE`.

Comment: i will surely check this out and let you know by tomorrow

Comment: tried doing it but no affect ,no change in my output

Comment: Can you edit the question and show the table schema, sample contents, and the expected results?

Comment: can you connect me through teamviewer ?

Comment: actually am new i rely don't know how to type the Db schema via text ,my requirement is if the data is already present in the table on a particular date  the user shouldn't be able to post any data on that particular day (submit button should be disabled)

Comment: Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` in a database query tool, paste the output into a code block in the question.